# Why do some C++ standard library `operator<<` functions reset their streams width to 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, language-lawyer

As stated in the `[ostream.inserters.character]` section of the C++ standard, after a `char` or string is inserted into a stream the stream's width is set to 0:

```
template<class traits>
  basic_ostream<char,traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char,traits>& out,
                                         const unsigned char* s);
Do lots of sensible and expected things...
Calls width(0).
```

Why does the C++ standard dictate a call to `width(0)`?

What is the rational for changing the streams width and not reseting it to its original value?
(As far as I know all other properties of a stream are preserved by the stream insertion operators.)

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532640/which-iomanip-manipulators-are-sticky), which demonstrates the confusion this causes, but does not explain why the standard dictates this behavior.

Comment: I don't want to write an answer, because only the people involved with this decision can say, but I'm very sure that the reason is convenience. The cases where you don't want to maintain `width` across multiple outputs heavily outweigh those where you do.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533752/341970) contains a *guess*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not to be "some" `operator<<` functions, in general Inserters and extractors (21.4.8.9). See [c++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) and a sensible reasoning in [Tony D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905467/whats-the-deal-with-setw/5905942#5905942)