# Convert Vector<int> to String

Tags: c++, string, vector

I want to make a program that first input array of string, then convert it into integer, and then push it to a vector.

The code is like this :

```
string a;
vector<long long int> c;
cout << "Enter the message = ";
cin >> a;   
cout << endl;

cout << "Converted Message to integer = ";
for (i=0;i<a.size();i++) 
{
    x=(int)a.at(i);
    cout << x << " "; //convert every element string to integer
    c.push_back(x);
}
```

The output :

```
Enter the message = haha
Converted Message to integer = 104 97 104 97
```

Then I write it in a file, and on the next program I want to read it back, and convert it back to string, my question will be how to do that? To convert the vector [104 97 104 97] back to string "haha".

I really appreciate any helps.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a vector<int> to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1430757/608639) and [Converting a vector<int> to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8581832/608639).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 std::vector<int> data = {104, 97, 104, 97};
std::string actualword;
char ch;
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

    ch = data[i];

    actualword += ch;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

> [...] my question will be how to do that? To convert the vector [104
>   97 104 97] back to string "haha".

That's very easy. You can loop through `std::vector` elements, and use **`std::string::operator+=`** overload to concatenate the characters (whose ASCII values are stored in the `std::vector`) in the resulting string.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = {104, 97, 104, 97};
  string s;

  for (auto x : v)
  {
    s += static_cast<char>(x);
  }

  cout << s << endl;
}
```

*Console output:*

> ```
> C:\TEMP\CppTests>g++ test.cpp
>
> C:\TEMP\CppTests>a.exe
> haha
> ```

---

Just a small note on your original code:

> x=(int)a.at(i);

You may want to use **C++-style casts** instead of old C-style casts in your code (i.e. `static_cast` in the above code).

Moreover, since you know the size of the vector, you should also know that valid indexes go from `0` to `(size-1)`, so using simple fast and efficient `std::vector::operator[]` overload is just fine, instead of using the `std::vector::at()` method (with its index bounds-checking overhead).

So, I'd change your code like this:

```
x = static_cast<int>( a[i] );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 104, 97, 104, 97 };

    std::string res(v.size(), 0);
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), res.begin(),
        [](int k) { return static_cast<char>(k); });

    std::cout << res << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Two notes:

1. It would be strongly advisable to change your vector to `std::vector<char>` - that would make this task easier, and `static_cast<char>(k)` is potentially dangerous.
2. Avoid C-style casts at all times. If you really need to, use `reinterpret_cast`, but in your case a `static_cast` would have done the trick as well. C-style casts do a lot of bad things, like implicit `const` casting or selling your soul.

Comment: Implicit const casting **IS** selling your soul.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah you're probably right, but I wasn't sure if everyone sees it that way. The one of us who sold their soul for a doughnut already may consider const casting as worse.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::string`'s iterator constructor:

```
std::vector<long long int> v{'h', 'a', 'h', 'a'}; //read from file
std::string s{std::begin(v), std::end(v)};
std::cout << s; //or manipulate how you want
```

It does beg the question why your vector contains `long long int` when it should only be storing characters, though. Watch out for that when trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: Will that work with vector of long long?

Comment: @NeilKirk, As long as they're all within range, which they'd better be. A vector of characters makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::transform using your own function object or lambda function making the reverse cast, i.e. (char)(int).