# Standard replacement for QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qbytearray

I want to port a Qt C++11 function to standard C++11. The function has a `QByteArray` parameter that accepts any kind of data (text, binary data, etc.) and calculates a hash from the data.

`QByteArray` seems well suited because it can carry any kind of data and has a lot of functions that allow filling it from streams, devices, strings, etc. **It even can wrap data without doing a deep copy using `fromRawData()`.**

Is there a standard C++11 solution that provides similar flexibility? Currently I tend to use good old `void*` plus size.

Comment: Just about any [STL container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) can store an array of (unsigned) characters.

Comment: @Raw N: How can a `vector<unsigned char>` be initialized from a pointer and size (or maybe a C string) without doing a deep copy?

Comment: `myVector.assign(pointer, pointer + size)` maybe? There are also around 7 [different constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: @Silicomancer If you don't want a deep copy, then use the pointer and the size. You already have them. Most of the standard library operations work over *iterator* ranges, so passing `ptr, ptr+size` as the range is very common. To be more direct, there is nothing remotely close to the breadth of functionality that QByteArray offers. Most of it would require you implementing the behavior.

Comment: @RawN ... does a value copy over the range. The specific method the OP mentioned was [fromRawData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData), and there is nothing like it that can be used via vector unless you get into some serious std::allocator overloading (and frankly, it wouldn't be worth the trouble).

Comment: `std::vector<uint8_t>` would seem to me to be the obvious replacement for `QByteArray` if you just want a container that can hold arbitrary binary data..

Comment: Hopefully we get `std::array_view` and that would work well in this case.  Right now I think you can get it as part of the core guidelines library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a standard C++11 solution that provides similar flexibility? Currently I tend to use good old void* plus size.

There's no standard C++11 solution that provides a container that can both manage its own memory or wrap memory managed by someone else.

You could simply copy the `QByteArray` (it's a few files) and bundle it with your project, if licensing terms allow.

Otherwise, if you only intend to work on containers with contiguous storage for all elements, the `const void*` and `size_t` arguments make perfect sense, and will be most portable and adaptable. You can provide convenience overloads as needed. E.g.

```
HashType calculateHash(const void*, size_t);

template <typename T> HashType calculateHash(const T& container) {
  static_assert(sizeof(typename T::value_type) == 1, "value_type must be byte-sized");
  assert(&container[container.size()-1] == &container[0]+container.size());
  return calculateHash(&container[0], container.size());
}
```

To support *any* container, even those with non-contiguous storage, the base `calculateHash` can take a range and offer an overload for hashing an entire container.

```
template <typename I>
HashType calculateHash(I start, I const end) {
  HashType hash;
  for (; start != end; ++start)
    hash.update(*start);
  return hash;
}

template <typename C>
HashType calculateHash(const C& container) {
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;
  return calculateHash(begin(container), end(container));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not know such kind of standard container that has the same complex functionality what QByteArray has but I would start with `std::vector< char >` and would implement a wrapper around that with the missing and necessary functions.

`std::vector` has high flexibility, you can access each element in constant time and you can easily convert it to std::string (for example [Converting a vector to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581832/converting-a-vector-to-string)).

If the *insert* operation is more important maybe you can try `std::list< char >`. Mainly this is linked list implementation.

Based on the comment from Jesper Juhl: using `uint8_t` as template argument would describe the real the *byte array* behavior.

Comment: But does it support wrapping data without doing a deep copy? If it doesn't I can't imagine how such a wrapper could do it.

Comment: With iterators or with operator[] you can access the element without deep copy.

Comment: @TiborTakács He means the ability to mimic the [**fromRawData**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData) functionality.

Comment: Not a very general use case but with special allocatior object you can theoretically do it. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator/

Comment: `char` would be a bad template argument for the vector since you don't know if it is signed or unsigned across implementations (there are *3* char types in C++; `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` and they are all different types to the type system & the signedness of `char` is implementation defined (yes, this *has* bitten me)). Better be specific and use `uint8_t` in this case (IMHO).

Comment: @Jesper Juhl I could agree, first I also thought to use `uint8_t` but QByteArray uses `char` therefore I thought `char` template argument more suit for the original behavior.

Comment: @Tibor Takács I know `QByteArray` uses `char` - I consider that (along with many other things) a failure on the part of the Qt developers.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite standard but you could use the [`view`/`span`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#SS-views) classes from the [Guideline Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) (which should eventually move over into the standard) to emulate `fromRawData`.

Of course, this does not deal with the lifetime issues that are related to the shared ownership but it might be sufficient in your cases.

Also, while it may not be a requirement for all components, the GSL is advertised as being C++14 based.