# formatting vector of int to a string

Tags: c++

So this is an exercise where I have to format a `std::vector<int>` into a `std::string`. The exercise requires us to only use stl algorithms, and we're not allowed to use for loops. `std::for_each` is allowed since it's part of algorithm too, but they rather not have us use it either.

The inputs are always sorted, and don't contain any duplicates.

| Input `std::vector<int>` | Output `std::string` |
| --- | --- |
| `{ 4, 8, 12}` | `"4, 8, 12"` |
| `{ -20, -19, .., .., 10, 11}` | `"[-20, 11]"` |
| `{ -5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 21}` | `"-5, [8, 12], 21"` |
| `{ -2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12 }` | `"-2, [5, 7], [10, 12]"` |

I was already looking into `std::search` and `std::adjacent_find` if I could use those, but I don't think they'll do what I need.

This is what I've tried. I also don't think this is a proper approach to solve this, since the complete exercise is meant to be about std algorithms, and I'm not using any here. Any suggestions to what stl algorithm could be handy in this case, would be greatly appreciated.

```
std::string FormatLine(int lineNumber)
{
    std::vector<int> input = { -2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13 };
    
    std::stringstream output{};
    int startNumber { input[0] };
    bool isRange{ false };
    
    for (int i{ 1 }; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        const int lastNumber = input[i - 1];
        
        // continue if its a incrementing sequence
        if (input[i] - 1 == lastNumber)
        {
            // if no range has been started yet, start one
            if (!isRange)
            {
                output << "[" << startNumber << ", ";
                isRange = true;
            }
            continue;
        }

        output << lastNumber;
        // if a range was started, close it with the last element of the range
        if (isRange)
        {
            output << "],";
            isRange = false;
        }
        // just a number so add a comment
        else
            output << ", ";
        
        startNumber = input[i];
    }
    // dont forget to add the last element
    output << input.back();
    // if it was still in a range, add closing bracket
    if (isRange) 
        output << ']';
    
    return output.str();
}
```

Comment: "The exercise requires us to only use stl algorithms" wow, there is still hope :). Please show your attempt. We arent going to write your homework for you but we can help, if you give us something to work with. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Does this article answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581832/converting-a-vectorint-to-string

Comment: @Attis No, the point of this question is to "squash" consecutive ranges into a different format than non-consecutive parts.

Comment: Once consecutive ranges are "squashed",  the output can be handled fairly easily using `std::copy()` and output stream iterators.    There will need to be some tweaking because, after outputting an `int` (e.g. from the vector), the following character needs to be a `','` in some cases and other characters in some particular cases.

Comment: I'll edit the post to show what I've tried so far. But it doesn't meet the requirements because it still uses a regular for loop. basicly a brute force solution ':)

Comment: If you already have a plain `for` loop, then try to convert the loop-body into a function taking only a single argument (the current value). Once you have that you can replace the loop with a `std::for_each` call.

Comment: I also mentioned it in the answer. The requirement to use `std::for_each` instead of loops is a little silly, because any loop can be rewritten as a call to `std::for_each`.

Comment: I updated the post. We are also allowed to use `std::for_each` but it is not mandatory, since they would like us to use some other stl algorithm if possible.

Comment: whats wrong with your code? What is "some problems" ?

Comment: it still using a normal for loop, and not using (barely) any stl algorithms as the (complete) exercise is heavily based on using them.

Comment: A quick-but-not-so-efficient-nor-clear implementation: https://wandbox.org/permlink/JA4oEXyjOLcHq2A3

Answer (score 1):

The solution cannot be a simple single loop, because you need to inspect later elements to know if the current element is prefixed with a `[`. Hence I propose to do some preprocessing.

The task asks to group numbers in intervals when the numbers are consecutive. To reflect that in code, use a structure:

```
 struct interval {
      int start;
      int size;          
 };
```

Also a single number can be represented as `interval` with size `0`. Now you can use a single pass through the vector to populate a `std::vector<interval>`.

I like the premise of only using standard algorithms, but ruling out loops in favour of `std::for_each` is a little silly, because in some sense range based loops are the modern `for_each` when the whole container is iterated.

```
 std::vector<interval> intervals;
 intervals.emplace_back(input[0],0);
 std::for_each( input.begin()+1,input.end(),[&invervals](int x){
      // check if x == intervals.back().start + intervals.back().size + 1
      // to decide if the last intervals size must be incremented
      // or a new interval be added
 });
```

Once you got that vector, you just need another loop to build the desired string. When `interval.size == 1` no `[` is prefixed and else `interval.start+interval.size-1 ]` is appended too.

There might be some off by one errors, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string get_string_expression(vector<int> & vec)
{
    int pre_iter = vec[0] - 2;
    vector<vector<int>> inter_result;

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&inter_result, &pre_iter](int iter) {     
        if (iter - pre_iter == 1)
        {
            inter_result.rbegin()->push_back(iter);
        }
        else
        {
            vector<int> temp = { iter };
            inter_result.push_back(temp);
        }       
        pre_iter = iter;
    });

    string result = "";
    for_each(inter_result.begin(), inter_result.end(), [&result](vector<int> iter) {
        if (iter.size() == 1)
        {
            result += to_string(iter[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            result += (string("[") + to_string(*iter.begin()) + "," + to_string(*iter.rbegin()) + "]");
        }
        result += ", ";
    });

    return result.substr(0, result.length() - 2);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> input_1 = { 4, 8, 12 };
    vector<int> input_2(32);
    vector<int> input_3 = { -5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 21 };
    vector<int> input_4 = { -2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12 };

    //. initialize input_2
    generate(input_2.begin(), input_2.end(), [n = -20]()mutable{ return n++; });

    cout << "input_1: " << get_string_expression(input_1) << endl;
    cout << "input_2: " << get_string_expression(input_2) << endl;
    cout << "input_3: " << get_string_expression(input_3) << endl;
    cout << "input_4: " << get_string_expression(input_4) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about accumulate? https://godbolt.org/z/xfK8acrT8

````
    std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    auto begin = arr.begin(), end = arr.end();
    
    std::string r;
    if (begin != end)
        r = std::to_string(*begin++);
    r = std::accumulate(begin, end, r, [](std::string result, int value) { result += ", " + std::to_string(value); return result; });
    std::printf("%s", r.c_str());```
````

yields:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```