# std::cout of the hexadecimal 0x00

Tags: c++, hex, iostream, iomanip

I've to print on the standard output some `std::uint16_t` values as hexadecimal with the following text formatting: `0x##`.
I found this code online which works fine for every value except `0`:

```
std::cout << std::internal 
          << std::setfill( '0' ) 
          << std::hex 
          << std::showbase 
          << std::setw( 4 ) 
          << value << std::endl;
```

For some reason I don't understand, `0` is printed as `0000`.
All the other values are correctly printed as expected.

Comment: As seen in the [Notes section here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase#Notes), this was a deliberate choice. How to get around it? Not sure, I'm afraid, never needed to. Sounds like you might need to get into creating your own [`num_put`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put), which is a pain in the proverbials.

Comment: _One question per question please._

Comment: I'm fairly sure a programmer designed this system ("Zero is the same in every base, what's the problem?").  I think `... << "0x" << setw(2) << ...` should work.

Answer (score 1):

For your additional question.
You only need to set the width again. The rest of the manipulators are persistent.

```
std::cout << std::internal 
      << std::setfill( '0' ) 
      << std::hex 
      << std::showbase ;

for(std::uint16_t i =1;i<255;++i){
      std::cout<< std::setw( 4 )<<i<<"\n";
}
```

To overcome the `setw` issue here are some workarounds: [“Permanent” std::setw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405039/permanent-stdsetw)