# Creating a hex representative from a std::array

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an `std::array` and I want to create a string from it by converting each byte to its equal HEX value something like this:

```
 string getString(array<unsigned char, 10> data)
 {
     // what is the faster way to do this?
 } 

main()
{
    array<unsigned char, 10> data={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   string result=getString(data);
   out<<result<<endl;
}
```

and it should print something such as:

```
0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
```

or even

00010203040506070809

any way that is faster.

I know that I can use a for loop and do this job, but if there any neater way to do this?

Comment: you can use `std::for_each(begin(data), end(data), ...);` but that's not a whole lot different than a range-`for` loop.

Comment: Just use a loop with `std::stringstream` and `std::hex`.

Comment: @DeiDei, why not submit this as an answer? (I might not fully understand SO etiquette....)

Comment: @MPops: Look at the sample code I posted which is what DeiDei is talking about

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below

```
string getString(array<unsigned char, 10> data)
{
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
   for(int i=0; i<data.size(); ++i)
      ss << std::setw(2) << (int)data[i];
   return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: You could use a range-for to make the purpose of the loop more immediately obvious, e.g., `for (const auto& c : data)` and then use `c` in place of `data[i]`

Comment: It can be done. We could even make use of std:for_each STL function

Comment: Certainly `std::for_each` would also work.  In a case like this I think the extra complexity of creating a lambda or function to apply to each element would make the code less readable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a bit of fun, you can use an [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
template<class Container>
std::string hex(Container const& c)
{
    std::stringstream out;
    std::copy(begin(c), end(c), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(out << std::hex, " "));
    return out.str();
}
```

#### Usage

```
std::cout << hex(array) << "\n";
```

#### Demo

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bc542742b1566e2

Comment: Also works for other standard containers (vector, list, ...) and other value_types (char, short, unsigned int, ...).

Comment: Can it output each byte as 2 hex digits always?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin not simply: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/405039/5470596